# How to solve "Invalid Service Account" Issue while installing win service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, setup-deployment, msbuildextensionpack

I am using Msbuild Extension Pack to install windows service remotely. Every time i try to deploy my application i get this wired error:

```
Install Service failed with code: 'StatusInvalidServiceAccount'
```

The account in remote server is set to log on as a service even though it doesn't solve the problem.

Note: This is a windows service created using Visual Studio 2010. I don't want Powershell to install this because of network issue in my environment.

Any help regarding the topic is really appriciated.

Comment: any codes you can show ?

Comment: How are you trying to install the service? installutil.exe?

Comment: i am using this  to install http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/258a18b7-2cf7-330b-e6fe-8bc45db381b9.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use domain account with while deploying services to remote machine and the account need to be set to login as a service.

```
Under <user>

and under <Remote User>
```

What ever use you put this user needs to be an administrator in both machines.